# Send Oracle Connection State to Label

Tags: c#, string, oracle, connection

Okay I'm working on a C# web app and I am trying to test the connection to my oracle database.  I would like to send the connection state to a label.  I don't know if I am using the commands  correctly (this is my first time using an oracle connection with C#).  Here is my code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=servername; Initial Catalog=dbname; User ID=userid; Password=password; Integrated Security=no;";
conn.Open();

string connstate;
conn.State.ToString(connstate);
Label_connectiontest.Text = connstate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just

```
 Label_connectiontest.Text = conn.State.ToString();
```

The State property of a IDbConnection object is an enum of type [ConnectionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the FlagAttribute set.

Applying the ToString method to this enum results in returning a value that is a string containing a delimiter-separated list of the names of the constants.

Comment: Okay, it's not throwing any errors or anything when I try that but it's not updating the label text at all.

Comment: Use the debugger and check if the code is executed. Stop after the assignement and verify if the Text property of the label has been changed. If yes, then the problem is elsewhere (form not displayed, label hidden, some overlapping controls, threads and so on)

Comment: Alright me being the idiot that I am had that under a catch statement.  My code is failing at the initial catalog so there must be something wrong with my connection string, more specifically at the initial catalog selection.